# How can I get component instance in vue template?

Tags: vue.js

I have such component template:

```
<input @change="$emit('my-event', this)"></div>
```

I supposed `this` will pass component using template to the event but I get `null`. How can I use component instance in template?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to create method and return `this`.

```
methods: {
  self() {
    return this;
  }
}
```

Implementing your example:

```
<input @change="$emit('my-event', self())"></div>
```